# Using External Assembly in BizTalk Script Functoid Configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, gac, class-library, biztalk-2013

In BizTalk Script Functoid Configuration  I want to use external assembly. I have create 2 functions.But if I want to update my external project by adding a new third function it doesn't appear in "Script method" dropdownlist. By the way I uninstall and install to GAC my updated application.

How can I see my new adding method in External Assembly?

Comment: Unfortunately , I couldnt add image post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by changing [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]  of app.config in my Helper Class.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio loads assemblies from the GAC only once. If you change the GAC after this one time loading has happened, you need to restart your Visual Studio to trigger a fresh load again. At this point, your new method should show up.